# UIkeyboardtypenumberpad IPAD

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uikeyboardtype

I was looking for UIkeyboardtypenumberpad but used in an iPad example.

I mean, it is possible to create a class or view which simulated just a numeric keyboard, like iPhone??

i am using 4.1 sdk version.

i don't want to use special characters, just numbers and dot.

thanks!!

Answer (score 8):

add `UITextFieldDelegate` in your header file (.h file)

```
txtfield_name.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;
txtfield_name.delegate=self;
```

then add this method

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

  NSString *validRegEx =@"^[0-9.]*$"; //change this regular expression as your requirement       
  NSPredicate *regExPredicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", validRegEx];
  BOOL myStringMatchesRegEx = [regExPredicate evaluateWithObject:string];   
  if (myStringMatchesRegEx)     
    return YES; 
  else
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Very clever - this also allows you to filter-out unwanted characters from external keyboards...

Comment: once again the power of regex is proved :) 1UP for predicate + regex